# SQL Remove Maximum per partition

Tags: sql

I would like not to take into consideration one row per id: PONUMBER that has multiple ORD
[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEEa4.png)

| PONUMBER | ORD | QTYORDER |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 200 |
| 1 | 2 | 100 |
| 1 | 3 | 100 |

As you may notice the QTYORDER is the sum of other lines, so I want not to take into consideration and remove it. In this example, we have the first line has the QTYORDER which the sum of other lines.

I was thinking about if QTY is the sum of other ORD per PONUMBER it should be remove.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number` like this:

```
with u as
(select *, 
row_number() over(partition by PONUMBER order by QTYORDER desc) as rn
from table_name)
select PONUMBER, ORD, QTYORDER from u
where rn <> 1;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=115680b6f237166701be35d80d5f6108)